# Decimal Representation without leading zeros of an integer in Java

Tags: java, math

I am a bit confused as to what will be a decimal representation without leading zeros of a non negative integer in Java be?
I read an example where 1213(integer value) was answered as 1213(decimal without leading zeros).

Can anyone please explain me this?

Answer (score 2):

It is just the way “normal people” would write down an integer number.

*Decimal* means that your integer representation uses base 10. That is, the digits from 0 through 9. (As opposed to, say, octal (base 8), where you'd only use the digits from 0 through 7.) Read up on “[positional notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation)” if you are not familiar with the concept.

*Without leading zeros* means that you don't put an insignificant `0` digit in front of any number other than 0. For example, you write `42`, not `042` and certainly not `00042`. “Normal people” occasionally use leading zeros to align numbers when writing dates (as in `29.02.`) or times (as in `01:07`) but apart from that, it's not very usual. “Computer people” often prefer to prefix numbers in a list with leading zeros until they are all of the same with because then sorting the list alphabetically yields the same order as sorting it numerically would.

*Non negative* just means that the exercise doesn't expect you to deal with negative numbers. It's not a requirement; just a simplification you're allowed to make.

Comment: Thanks alot. Could you please tell me that my problem says , Two numbers N, M are similar if their decimal representation( without leading zeros) can be obtained from each other by rearranging the digits. So, here if N=210, can M=012 ?

Comment: @Ayush what is the problem you are having and what have you tried?

Comment: The problem is to find all the possible values of N, where M=210. So, should I include '012' also here ?

Comment: @Ayush `012` has a leading zero.

Comment: @Ayush Sorry, I don't understand that last question. Your original post doen't talk about “similar numbers” and it's also not a mathematical concept I'm aware of. Of course, your exercise is free to *define* „similar“ in that way. But I don't know what your exercise says beyond what you have posted. Generally, words that can be obtained from other words by permuting their letters are called [*anagrams*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram).

Comment: @PeterLawrey Please tell me that according to the problem, should I take 012 in account or not ?

Comment: @Ayush it depends on what the problem says. I suggest you read the task given and do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's decimal i.e. base 10 using digits 0 to 9, and there are no leading zeros.

If it was a 16-bit binary, with leading zeros it might look like

```
00000101001010101
```

> , Two numbers N, M are similar if their decimal representation( without leading zeros) can be obtained from each other by rearranging the digits. So, here if N=210, can M=012

The simple solution is to sort the digits and compare them. O(N ln N)

The more advanced solution is to count the number of digits and compare that O(N). Note with Java 8 you can do this with 1-3 lines of code.

> The problem is to find all the possible values of N, where M=210

That's a different problem. You need to generate all the combinations. If you can't have leading zeros, skip all the solutions which start with a zero.

Comment: Is the decimal value same as of the value of non negative integer always?

Comment: @Ayush Decimals can be negative e.g. -1 is negative and a decimal.